# Why were blocking calls invented when the underlying nature of computers is a state machine?

Tags: c

I understand that implementing a state machine is the perfect way to program the computer. Since state machines are typically programmed using non-blocking calls, I wonder why blocking calls similar to the Berkeley sockets APIs were invented? Don't they encourage bad programming practice?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: The idea behind this question is to establish the fact that a multi-context event driven state machine based on non-blocking IO is indeed the perfect way to program the computer. Everything else is amateur. People who think otherwise should allow for a debate.

Comment: I have no idea how you have linked blocking calls with state machines. A blocking call can be very well described as a state self-transition.

Comment: Blocking calls *in general* are completely natural for a single thread of execution.  They came along with the invention of functions and subroutines.  Perhaps you mean to ask something much narrower?  Such as why we have both blocking and non-blocking **I/O**?

Comment: Eugene, John:I meant a state machine that caters multiple contexts. I hope now my question is clearer.

Comment: Regardless, our focus here is on practical, answerable questions about *the practice of writing software*. Theoretical or academic questions have different homes on the StackExchange network.

Comment: @Charles Duffy This question is about the practice of writing software, and has a definite answer.

Comment: If your question is "Don't they encourage bad programming practice?", then the answer is "No".

Comment: This may be about the history of the practice, but this history has no practical value: No answer can be reasonably expected to impact the manner in which someone writes code today. Hence, the question is academic in nature.

Comment: The other context is that we prefer questions that generate light to those that result in heat (disagreement without illumination). Thus far, this appears to be the latter.

Comment: @Charles I agree with your last comment. But the kind of responses I've got are nothing short of brilliant. I think I can eventually prove blocking calls are useless.

Comment: @samofoz youi cannot.

Comment: @Martin I have done similar adventures in the past. I am confident.

Comment: Sure thing you can implement any blocking call using a non-blocking one and a `while` loop. So? Does it make them useless?

Comment: @samofoz if the box is idle,and there happens to be no input of any kind ATM, what is your non-blocking design going to do?  Make up some work?

Comment: @EugeneSh. they are useless if you office is cold and you really need a fan heater.  Having all 16 cores on halt does not help with your chilblains.

Comment: @MartinJames Come on, it was a simplification. You can stick some `WFI` in the middle (sorry, on ARM now...). But it's like saying we don't need a multiplication operator as we can do multiplication by addition...

Comment: @EugeneSh. it might be a simplification, but I thought it was pretty accurate:)

Comment: @Eugene There is no need for a while loop - its the ugly way to do it. The way it is suppose to work is that the program issues a non blocking call and immediately moves on to the next event (which could belong to another context). When that non- blocking call finishes, it posts an event for its context. If an asynchronous event arrives for that context in between, the call is cancelled mid way using something like a cancelIO().

Answer (score 3):

Your question makes some pretty substantial assertions / assumptions:

> the underlying nature of computers is a state machine?

Well, surely you can *model* computers as state machines, but that does not in itself mean that such a model represents some fundamental "underlying nature".

> I understand that implementing a state machine is the perfect way to program the computer.

Then by all means, write all your programs as state machines.  Good luck.

In real life, some tasks can be conveniently and effectively written as state machines, but there are many for which a state-machine approach would be cumbersome to write and difficult to understand or maintain.

There is no "perfect" way to program a computer.  Indeed, it would be pretty pretentious to claim perfection even for a single program.

> Since state machines are typically programmed using non-blocking calls,

You don't say?  I think you would need to be a lot more specific about what you mean by this.  I have written state-machine based software at times in the past, and I would not characterize any of it as having been implemented using non-blocking calls, nor as exposing a non-blocking external API.

> I wonder why blocking calls similar to the Berkeley sockets APIs were invented? Don't they encourage bad programming practice?

Before we could even consider this question, you would have to define what you mean by "bad programming practice".  From what I can see, however, you are assuming the conclusion:

- you ***assert*** that a state-machine approach to programming is ideal, with the implication that anything else is sub-par.
- you ***claim***, without support, that only non-blocking calls have state-machine nature
- you conclude that anything that uses blocking calls must exhibit bad programming practice.

Your conclusion is not consistent with the prevailing opinion and practice of the programming community, to the extent that I can gauge it.  Your argument is hollow and unconvincing.

Comment: You are obviously right about the fact that almost every word in my question is debatable. But I wonder why won't you agree that a computer is nothing but a state machine?

Comment: Why would I agree with such an absurd proposition, @samofoz?  Even if, *arguendo*, I were to accept that a computer could be completely characterized as a state machine, saying that it is *nothing but* a state machine denies alternative characterizations, of which, in reality, there are many.

Comment: Are these alternative characterizations used in practice? Where? Thx.

Comment: Yes, @samofoz, they are used in practice.  The best example is probably the Turing machine, which, I suspect you know, is used ubiquitously in computer science theory.  Shall I argue that because all computations can be modeled via Turing machines, and Turing machines are fundamentally sequential, that the existence of *non*-blocking functions encourages bad programming practice?  I won't, because such an argument would be as vacuous as your own.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple processes (or later, threads) with synchronous (blocking) calls are *easy to understand and program* and *easily composable* - that is, you can take two tasks that are made up of synchronous calls and run them at the same time (via a scheduler) without having to modify either one in any way.

Programming as a state machine, on the other hand, requires either manually adding states (possibly in combinatorically growing numbers) when you add new code, or some kind of tightly-coupled framework of registering handlers and explicitly storing state for the next handler to use.

Comment: I think any task can be programmed as an event driven state machine - no need for blocking calls. Because the underlying nature of blocking calls (and even the computer!) is a state machine, why not program tasks as state machines. Its easier that way.

Comment: What about the state machine *itself* @samofoz?

Comment: @samofoz Empirical evidence suggests that "Its easier that way." is a false statement, programs and algorithms written with blocking calls are simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: @samofoz Any task. You are right. This is what the underlying computer logic is doing. But the number of states is growing exponentially with the task complexity, so it needs an abstraction badly. And this is what is provided by imperative/functional/logical programming languages.

Comment: @Eugene Don't you think any program that ignores some states is buggy?

Comment: @samofoz How is it related? Yes, if a program is transitioning to a state it is not intended to transition, yes it is buggy.

Comment: @Eugene Its related. I think blocking calls result in buggy, unreadable programs - need a solid answer to be convinced otherwise.

Comment: What's wrong with "Wait for input" state, which is transitioning into itself as long as there is no input? This is exactly what a blocking input function is doing.

Comment: What state is a program which performs a blocking call ignoring? As far as its world is concerned, what happens to the machine while it is blocked (running other processes) is completely invisible.

Comment: @Matteo I am sure you are aware of the POSIX error code EINTR. Don't you think proper handling of this error code makes the program ugly and hence should classify under "bad programming practice"?

Comment: @samofoz, ...I assume you're familiar with [The Rise of "Worse is Better"](https://www.jwz.org/doc/worse-is-better.html)? (Not that we're anywhere *near* staying on-topic at this point, but it's very much part of the cannon that anyone on the topics we're discussing should be aware of).

Comment: @samofoz: `EINTR` and wild UNIX-style signals are ugly UNIX artifacts, and should die in hell. There's nothing like `EINTR` in e.g. Windows NT - which still sports (optionally) blocking calls (although it must be said that at its core all IO is asynchronous); the most similar thing is the way more civilized `CancelIO`, which is only on request, and APCs (which, again, are only on request).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: The narrative in that essay is factually wrong. `EINTR` was not "worse is better", but part of a failed attempt (fundamental race conditions) to make it possible to timeout/cancel stuck blocking operations.

Comment: @R There is an alternative to registering handlers. A program's main event handler (i.e. where the state machine is implemented) thread polls the underlying system for only its own contexts' events. That way programs can  be independent. Programs written that way are easy to understand and easily composable because its close to the state machine nature of the computer - whats happening underneath is what's happening at the top.

Comment: It's actually quite difficult to find any examples of apps that do not make blocking calls.  TCP servers that use the select() call are often described as 'non-blocking' which, on the face of it, is ridiculous because select() is a blocking call.  What is meant is that 'all relevant events are channeled into one blocking call and the user has to write an FSM to implement stuff'.  This is, aparrently, so 'easy' that most net examples of such a design are just echo servers, since any protocol more complex would require a context object instance per client and the newbies' brains would explode.

Answer (score 1):

What?  'blocking call' implies preemptive multitasking. The kernel of such an OS is a state-machine with interrupts as input events and a set of running threads as output actions.

The OS kernel is a state machine, and blocking calls conveniently move the FSM functionality into the kernel so that you don't have to write the miserable state-machines in user apps.

> I understand that implementing a state machine is the perfect way to program the computer

What?  'perfect'?  What?   Have you ever developed, debugged and delivered any non-trivial multithreaded app?

Comment: What happens if you need to preempt a blocked thread? In other words, how to handle asyncronous events in a blocked thread? Doesn't EINTR result in ugly code? I have developed, debugged and delivered many multithreaded apps.

Comment: I don't understand 'preempt a blocked thread'; it's not running. If it's not running, you cannot preempt it.  It's not using any CPU to preempt.

Comment: If there is an asynchronous event of interest to the thread, then I would assume that the thread is waiting for that event.

Comment: When I say "preempt a blocked thread", I mean the need to return from a blocked call as a result of any external (asynchronous) event. Sorry, I am struggling to frame sentences.